# Nested ajax calls using promise

Tags: jquery, ajax, kendo-ui, promise, kendo-asp.net-mvc

I need to refactor a standard ajax pyramid using Promise. Initially I was using standard AJAX calls with `async:false`. This has made the page to be slower. So I decided to replace nested AJAX calls with AJAX Promise.

This is my original ajax call.

```
$.ajax({
            type:"POST",
            url:'@Url.Action("GetDesks", "OrderForm")',
            data:{ String(agents.val())},
            async:false,
            success:function (desks) {
                if (desks!=undefined || desks!=null || desks!= '') {
                    var deskList=$("#DeskList").data("kendoDropDownList");
                    deskList.dataSource.data(desks);
                    deskList.value("");
                    deskList.trigger('change');
                    var desklist = $.map(desks, function(val,index) {     
                        return val.Value;
                    }).join(",");                   
                    $.ajax({
                        type:"POST",
                        url:'@Url.Action("GetUsers", "OrderForm")',
                        data:{ Desks:desklist },                        
                        async:false,
                        success:function (users) { 
                            if (users!=undefined || users!=null || users!= '') {
                                var usersList=$("#DeskUsers").data("kendoDropDownList");
                                usersList.dataSource.data(users);
                                usersList.select(0);
                                usersList.refresh();
                            }
                        },
                    });
                }
            },

        });
```

I tried to modify the above as:

```
$.ajax({
            type:"POST",
            url:'@Url.Action("GetDesks", "OrderForm")',
            data:{ String(agents.val())}
        }).done(function (desks) {  
            if (desks!=undefined || desks!=null || desks!= '') {
                var deskList=$("#DeskList").data("kendoDropDownList");
                deskList.dataSource.data(desks);
                deskList.value("");
                deskList.trigger('change');
                var desklist = $.map(desks, function(val,index) {     
                    return val.Value;
                }).join(",");                   
                $.ajax({
                    type:"POST",
                    url:'@Url.Action("GetUsers", "OrderForm")',
                    data:{ Desks:desklist }
                })
                //How to apply promise after this?
        });
```

I applied promise to fist ajax call. But a little confusion while applying the same to second ajax call.

How could I apply the promise for above case?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With a few assumptions, you seem to want something like this :

```
$.ajax({
    url: '@Url.Action("GetDesks", "OrderForm")',
    type: 'POST',
    data: { 'Agents': agents.val() } //probably?
}).then(function (desks) {
    if (desks) {
        return $.ajax({
            url: '@Url.Action("GetUsers", "OrderForm")',
            type: 'POST',
            data:{ 'Desks': $.map(desks, function(val) { return val.Value; }).join() }
        }).then(function (users) {
            if (users) {
                // `desks` is still in scope allowing *both* kendoDropDownLists to be updated together
                var usersList = $("#DeskUsers").data("kendoDropDownList");
                usersList.dataSource.data(users);
                usersList.select(0);
                usersList.refresh();
                var deskList = $("#DeskList").data("kendoDropDownList");
                deskList.dataSource.data(desks);
                deskList.value("");
                deskList.trigger('change'); //probably do this last?
            } else {
                return new Error('No users found');
            }
        }, function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
            return new Error(textStatus);
        });
    } else {
        return new Error('No desks found');
    }
}, function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
    return new Error(textStatus);
}).fail(function(error) {
    console.log(error);
});
```

Apart from using promises, the main change is to move `$("#DeskList").data("kendoDropDownList")...` into the second "success handler".

This will guarantee that both lists are updated, or neither of them, and affords the opportunity to `.trigger('change') after both lists have been updated, which may be important. Promises are actually not necessary for this aspect - you could do the same in the original code (even with async:true).

Comment: Sorry for the delay. I tried your code but getting an error like `$.map(...).get is not a function`. Googling the issue, found that .map(), and $.map() are two different things.

Comment: I beg your pardon, `$.map()` returns an array. I was thinking of `jQueryCollection.map()`, which returns an array wrapped in another jQuery object. Answer edited.

Comment: Thanks @Roamer-1888, with few modifications you code is working fine.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, don't use `async: false`. I also have no idea what the `data: {String(agents.val())}` syntax is, but you can improve your code as:

```
$.post('@Url.Action("GetDesks", "OrderForm")', { Agents: String(agents.val()) }).then(function(desks) {
    if (desks != undefined || desks != null || desks != '') {

        var deskList = $("#DeskList").data("kendoDropDownList");
        deskList.dataSource.data(desks);
        deskList.value("");
        deskList.trigger('change');

        var desklist = $.map(desks, function(val, index) {
            return val.Value;
        }).join(",");

        return $.post('@Url.Action("GetUsers", "OrderForm")', { Desks: desklist }).then(function() {
            if (users != undefined || users != null || users != '') {
                var usersList = $("#DeskUsers").data("kendoDropDownList");
                usersList.dataSource.data(users);
                usersList.select(0);
                usersList.refresh();
            }
        });
    }
}).then(function() {
    // both operatioins are completed
});
```

Comment: I used async: false to delay the kendoDropdownlist filtering before the next ajax call.

Answer (score 0):

I have never used ajax promises. I have only used in as3.

However, if you want them to execute asynch, leave your GetDesks the same. Take the GetUsers outside of the success handler inside of the first .done, and execute it in the next line similar to before.

eg.

GetUsers.done(func...);

GetDesks.done(func...);

Answer (score 0):

To combine the handlers is to use the then() method of the Promise interface

It accepts all three handlers as arguments. With regards to jQuery, prior to version 1.8,

you could pass an array of functions to the then() method:

Like This

```
$.ajax({url: "/ServerResource.txt"}).then([successFunction1, successFunction2, successFunction3], 
                                          [errorFunction1, errorFunction2]);

//same as

var jqxhr = $.ajax({
  url: "/ServerResource.txt"
});

jqxhr.done(successFunction1);
jqxhr.done(successFunction2);
jqxhr.done(successFunction3);
jqxhr.fail(errorFunction1);
jqxhr.fail(errorFunction2);
```

Comment: In this case, how could I pass the success value from successFunction1 to next AJAX post?